# window.open is not a function error, Please help. I have looked everywhere, cant understand

Tags: jquery, window.open

link to video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MY1JKlJj7aY

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="window.open('/index/11','upp','scrollbars=1,top=0,left=0,resizable=1,width=680,height=350');return false;" rel="nofollow" class="profile-settings" title="Hастройки"></a>
```

Website: http://tmptstdays4god.ucoz.com/load/test_1/zavet_music/2-1-0-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have assigned some value to window.open someplace in your script. Look for code upstream that may have done this accidentally.

This reproduces your problem:

```
window.open = "no such function";
window.open('/index/11','upp','scrollbars=1,top=0,left=0,resizable=1,width=680,height=350');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9aktx53g/

Comment: I tried to remove the  whole code in /js/jQuery,scripts.js... but don't seem to see that kind of code. 
Ok, the issue was with open = false;

Answer (score 2):

If you have overwritten the `window` property you can ether call `open` on its own or get the global context using the following trick (doesn't work for strict mode):

```
new Function('return this;')().open('/index/11','upp','scrollbars=1,top=0,left=0,resizable=1,width=680,height=350');
```

You can also refer to window as `self` or (`parent` and `top` if you are not in a frame):

```
console.log(window === self); // true
console.log(window === parent); // true if no frames
console.log(window === top); // true if no frames
```

Comment: the issue was I defined a global variable as open and set it to false, because I use that to know if the popup is open or not. I didn't know that this was going to interfere with window.open() function.